# Establish TCP connection between hosts

Tags: mininet, openflow, pox

If my designated controller succeeded to ping between two hosts, is it possible to make TCP connection between them via Mininet? I did `mininet>h0 ping h4` successfully but pinging is just ICMP packets not TCP!!

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by the word "establish"?

Comment: I mean start TCP connection between the two hosts. I did `mininet>h0 ping h4` successfully but pinging is just ICMP packets not TCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ping was ok you can try iperf which will test bandwidth over TCP (read here  https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Bufferbloat#part-3-streaming-video---sketch-the-tcp-cwnd-and-buffer-occupancy)
You could also try to setup a simple http server on mininet on some host which will stand over TCP.

```
mininet> h1 python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80 &
mininet> h2 wget -O - h1
```

Both of the above should work and give you TCP connections

Answer (score 0):

You should first check the rule that is enabling the communication between the hosts with the following command (imagine the switch is *s1*):

```
mininet> ovs-ofctl dump-flows s1
```

and check the **IP protocol** field that is matching against the flow entries. For TCP the value should be 6, 17 in the case of UDP and 1 for ICMP. You can check all the protocol numbers here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in some cases where the delay of link are very high. Then the SYN packet wont get ACK within TCP timeout.  for eg, try with linear topology in mininet with 3 hosts and link delay is 3000ms(--link=tc,delay=3000ms). In this case your ping will work but not tcp iperf.